# dynamic sort columns doesn't work in linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

in linq i'm tring to create gridview with dynamic sort  columns 
can any one help me what is worng on below code and why it does't work

```
// i created this function to get column value which i need to sorty by 
private static string GetReflectedPropertyValue( object subject, string field)
        {
            object reflectedValue = subject.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(subject, null);
            return reflectedValue != null ? reflectedValue.ToString() : "";
        }
```

```
// this is my grid query 
List<ticketSearchRes> tickets = new List<ticketSearchRes>();
// here i deteermined sort direction ascending or desc
            bool asc = (gridViewInputsVM.SortDirection == "asc") ? true : false;
            bool desc = (gridViewInputsVM.SortDirection != "asc") ? true : false;
            IQueryable<ticketSearchRes> source = (from ticket in _db.TblTicket
                                                  where (searchRes.assignTic == 1) ? ticket.AssignedTo == CurrentuserId : true
                                                  where (searchRes.myTicket == 1 && searchRes.forOthers != 1) ? ticket.CreatedFor == CurrentuserId : true
                                                       orderby
                                                  asc ? GetReflectedPropertyValue(ticket, "TicketTitle") : "",
// here i need to get dynamic column which i need to sort by 
                                                  desc ? GetReflectedPropertyValue(ticket, "TicketTitle") : ""  descending  // doesn't work
                                                  select new ticketSearchRes
                                                  {
                                                      title = (ticket.TicketTitle != null) ? ticket.TicketTitle.ToString() : "",
                                                      ticId = ticket.TicketId.ToString()     
 }).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would solve this is;

The partial class `TicketSearchResList` is part that fills in the partial method `CustomSort`. CustomSort accepts a property name and a sort direction and uses Reflection to sort on the named property. So far it should be easy to follow.

```
public partial class TicketSearchResList : List<TicketSearchRes>
{
    partial void CustomSort(string propertyName, string direction);

    public void Dump()
    {
        CustomSort("TicketTitle", "desc");

        foreach(var ticket in this)
            Console.WriteLine(ticket.ToString()); // For demo purposes
    }
}


public partial class TicketSearchResList {

    private string propertyName;
    private string direction;

    partial void CustomSort(string propertyName, string direction)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.direction = direction;
        Sort(Comparer);
    }

    private int Comparer(TicketSearchRes x, TicketSearchRes y)
    {
        int directionChanger = direction == "asc" ? 1 : -1;

        try
        {
            PropertyInfo lhs = x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            PropertyInfo rhs = y.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);     

            object o1 = lhs.GetValue(x, null);
            object o2 = rhs.GetValue(y, null);

            if(o1 is IComparable && o2 is IComparable)
            {
                return ((IComparable)o1).CompareTo(o2) * directionChanger;
            }

            // No sort
            return 0;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Should log something
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

The comparison is done using Reflection in the Comparer method. The direction is
used to determine whether to multiply the result by 1 or -1. `CompareTo` returns
an integer where -1 means less than, 0 means equal to, and 1 means greater than. Thus, if
you multiply the result by -1, you change the direction of the sort.

Finally, the `TicketSearchResList` class inherits from `List<TicketResearchRes>`. As you can see, the Dump method calls CustomSort, which, if implemented, yields ordered output.

Also, have a look at the `Sort` Method documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) by Microsoft